# Securing NIFI with SSL Comodo Cert

Tags: ssl, openssl, apache-nifi

I'm trying to secure our NIFI environment with SSL. I'm gettin the following error:

```
This site can’t provide a secure connection <I.P> uses an unsupported protocol.
ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH
```

I got a Comodo certificate that i requested at my org and got it approved. I have a .key as well which was generated during CSR. I imported the comodo cert into the keystore. Then, I imported both the comodo root cert and .key into truststore. NIFI version is 1.9.2

nifi.properties:

```
nifi.security.keystoreType=JKS
nifi.security.keystorePasswd=mypassword
nifi.security.keyPasswd=
nifi.security.truststore=./conf/truststore.jks
nifi.security.truststoreType=JKS
nifi.security.truststorePasswd=mypassword
nifi.security.user.authorizer=managed-authorizer
nifi.security.user.login.identity.provider=
nifi.security.ocsp.responder.url=
nifi.security.ocsp.responder.certificate=
```

last few lines of the logs:

```
2019-07-12 02:29:55,877 INFO [main] o.eclipse.jetty.server.AbstractConnector Started ServerConnector@45e97963{SSL,[ssl, http/1.1]}{0.0.0.0:8443}
2019-07-12 02:29:55,877 INFO [main] org.eclipse.jetty.server.Server Started @28943ms
2019-07-12 02:29:55,906 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarAutoLoader Starting NAR Auto-Loader for directory ./extensions ...
2019-07-12 02:29:55,907 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.nar.NarAutoLoader NAR Auto-Loader started
2019-07-12 02:29:55,907 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer NiFi has started. The UI is available at the following URLs:
2019-07-12 02:29:55,907 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer https://<I.P>:8443/nifi
2019-07-12 02:29:55,907 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.web.server.JettyServer https://127.0.0.1:8443/nifi
2019-07-12 02:29:55,909 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.BootstrapListener Successfully initiated communication with Bootstrap
2019-07-12 02:29:55,909 INFO [main] org.apache.nifi.NiFi Controller initialization took 19369037824 nanoseconds (19 seconds).
```

Answer (score 0):

Can you show the output of using the OpenSSL `s_client` tool to connect to the host? I'm assuming `<I.P>` is a manual substitution for the actual host IP? Using this version of NiFi, the certificate must have valid *SubjectAlternativeName* entries for the hostname(s) and IP address(es) you wish to access the service using.

You also want to ensure that the *keystore* contains the *public certificate* and *private key*. The *truststore* should contain the *public certificate* and any CA certificates used to sign it (depending on your threshold for desired specificity on accepting incoming certificates for client certificate authentication).

Comment: thanks for your response Andy. yes, <I.P> is the actual I.P of the server. When i try to import the private key into keystore, i get an err keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate

Comment: Please show the commands you are using to import the key. We've collected a [list of helpful commands for NiFi certificate handling](https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/html/toolkit-guide.html#additional_certificate_commands) here. You probably want to execute commands 5 and 6.

Comment: I combine PKEY and PubCert into PKCS12 first. `openssl pkcs12 -export -out keystore.p12 -inkey $(hostname).key -in $(hostname).pem` . Then i convert it into keystore format. `keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore keystore.p12 -srcstoretype pkcs12 -destkeystore keystore.jks -deststoretype jks` Then I import the Public Cert into the trust store. `keytool -importcert -trustcacerts -file dscsqa-po-01.sys.comcast.net.pem -alias comodo_cert -keystore truststore.jks
  687  2019-07-15 15:57:15 keytool -importcert -trustcacerts -file $(hostname).pem -alias comodo_cert -keystore keystore.jks`

Comment: You can use `keytool -list -v -keystore keystore.jks` to show the contents of the keystore and verify there is a `privateKeyEntry` which has `SubjectAlternativeName` entries which match the IP/hostname of the server you are deploying to.

Comment: Hi Andy - Thanks for your response. I checked the Keystore and it contains 1 Entry, "PrivateKeyEntry" and it has the SAN as the hostname of the server that i'm deploying to. I checked the truststore and it has 2 entires, the signed certificate that was given to me by my org and the root certificate.

Comment: You will probably need more details from [the output of `openssl s_client`](https://www.feistyduck.com/library/openssl-cookbook/online/ch-testing-with-openssl.html) at this point. You can use this tool to attempt a TLS connection and see extensive information about the handshake negotiation and certificate exchange.